# codename one remove back button on ios

Tags: codenameone

I removed the title of the form because I don't want it. when I did that, a back button on the iOS(On android back button does not show) started to show on the bottom of the form.

[image]

I've tried to override showForm() in the StateMachine and invoke setTitle("") but the back button is still there.

```
@Override 
public Form showForm(String resourceName, Command sourceCommand) {

Form f = super.showForm(resourceName, sourceCommand);
f.setTitle("");

return f;

};
```

Is there a way to remove that back button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the way. Override allowBackTo as:

```
protected boolean allowBackTo(String formName) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this in an "old GUI builder" app?

Comment: This is only for the old GUI builder. The new GUI builder doesn't have these sort of problems