# Codename One: Switch Form

Tags: codenameone

I tried a simple project with 2 forms: Login and MainMenu

I made GUI with Codename One design:

[image]

I checked in StateMachineBase class, I think it for LoginForm (the first form)

[image]

And now, I want to click on Login button it will open MainMenuForm, but I don't know how to do.
Can you help me, maybe some tutorial or simple sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html it covers pretty much everything.

The state machine base shouldn't be modified. Just select the login button and do one of two things:

Click the Action Event button and then when you are sent to the Statemachine class where the callback method would be added you can just use code like:

```
showForm("MainMenuForm", null);
```

Alternatively you can select the Command property of the login button and select that it would be a navigation command that will lead you to the main menu form. This is done entirely in the GUI builder with no code required.

Comment: Thank for help. Now I meet a problem after I showForm: http://gyazo.com/77533b96d0c29975ffeb0ae6316c9a6b. 
I don't want to show the default bottom (footer) container, because I added it by myseft.
Can you help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think it's Title Bar, if I enter title "My form" for Form, the Title Bar is showed at Top, and "footer" is hidden.

Comment: You need to disable the back command functionality see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741498/codename-one-remove-back-button-on-ios I suggest filing a separate question for other things since its hard to provide decent answers in the comments and moderators might not look on this kindly.